# nx: use @tailwind keyword in a lib

Tags: tailwind-css, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I'm creating a `styling` library in my monorepo, and I want this library to import classes from the tailwindcss library, as well as define a couple more custom classes (with `@apply` keyword), like so

```
/*libs/shared/ui-styles/src/lib/styles.css*/
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .btn {
    @apply focus:outline-none py-2 px-4 rounded transition ease-in-out duration-150 inline-flex items-center;
  }
}
```

With the following update to the build target options in my `workspace.json` file

```
"styles": ["apps/example/src/styles.css", "libs/shared/ui-styles/src/lib/styles.css"],
```

This does not load the tailwindcss classes when I run my application.
If I add the tailwind imports to the `css` file of my application, it does work, but I want to extract this to my `styling` library.

Can someone tell me how to make the `@tailwind` keyword work in my library?
Thank you

Ps. any other "normal" css (for example css variables) in that library file works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question as a found a solution.
I've installed the `postcss-import` plugin, and added it to the `postcss.config.js`file in my application.

Now I can have a library for all my global styles (including the `@tailwind` imports), and then simply import this stylesheet from the library in my applications with the `@import` keyword.

This will still purge all the unnecessary classes that are not used in my applications.